# How to sequentially call promises with $q

Tags: angularjs, promise

I would like to call setup method in an angular controller that fetches all the relevant component parts it needs to continue. I'm sure I should be using promises, but I'm a little confused about the proper usage. Consider this:

I have a ShellController that needs to fetch the currently logged in user, then display their name on-screen, then fetch some customer details and display them on screen. If at any point this sequence fails, then I need a single place for it to fail. Here's what I have so far (not working ofc).

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('ShellController', function($q, ShellService) {
  var shell = this;
  shell.busy = true;
  shell.error = false;

  activate();

  function activate() {

    var init = $q.when()
      .then(ShellService.getUser())
      .then(setupUser(result)) //result is empty
      .then(ShellService.getCustomer())
      .then(setupCustomer(result)) // result is empty
      .catch(function(error) { // common catch for any errors with the above
        shell.error = true;
        shell.errorMessage = error;
      })
      .finally(function() {
        shell.busy = false;
      });
  }

  function setupUser(user) {
    shell.username = user;
  }

  function setupCustomer(customer) {
    shell.customer = customer;
  }
});

app.service('ShellService', function($q, $timeout) {

  return {
    getUser: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve('User McUserface');
      }, 2000);

      return deferred.promise;
    },
    getCustomer: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve('Mary Smith');
      }, 2000);

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ShellController as shell">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="shell.error">
      An error occurred! {{ shell.errorMessage }}
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-info" ng-show="shell.busy">
      Fetching details...
    </div>
    <div>Username: {{ shell.username }}</div>
    <div>Customer: {{ shell.customer }}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What should I be doing here?

Comment: a `then` function returns a promise that will be resolved with the value you will return from within the `then` e.g. `.then(function() { return 1 }).then(function(value) { console.log(value); // 1 });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs little changes. `.then()` receives a callback reference, rather than another promise. So here

```
.then(ShellService.getUser())
```

you're passing a promise as parameter. You should pass a *callback that returns a resolving value or a promise* as parameter to allow chaining

Also the initial `$q.when` is not necessary, since your first function already returns a promise. You should do something like this:

```
ShellService.getUser()
      .then(setupUser(result)) //result is empty
      .then(ShellService.getCustomer)
      .then(setupCustomer)
      .catch(function(error) { // common catch for any errors with the above
        shell.error = true;
        shell.errorMessage = error;
      })
      .finally(function() {
        shell.busy = false;
      });
```

Comment: You've still got some parameters should be callable but are called too soon. e.g. `setupUser(result)` should be `setupUser` and also `setupCustomer(result)` should be `setupCustomer`.